# How to get user input to display cell data in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to get Python to read an Excel file using `openpyxl`. I need to get the user to enter a student ID number, and Python will return the student name. I'm stuck.

Any help is really appreciated!

With what I have so far, I only get `Not found`

```
import openpyxl
roster = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
sheet = roster.active

st_id = int(input("Enter student ID: "))

col3 = sheet['C']
for cell in col3:
    if cell.value == st_id:
        print(cell)
    else:
        print('Not found.')
```

[sample.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BsXK.png)

Comment: Hi, can you post a sample of your `.xlsx` data?

Comment: Maybe cell.value is a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better iterate over all the rows in your Excel file. You can do it like this:

```
    for row in sheet.rows:
        if row[2].value == st_id:
            print("First Name: {}\tLast Name: {}".format(row[0].value, row[1].value))
        else:
            print('Not found.')
```

This will print the input student info and `Not found.` for any other row in the table, same as your original implementation.
If you want to print `Not found.` only if the input `ID` is **not** in the Excel file you can use `for-else` like this:

```
  for row in sheet.rows:
        if row[2].value == st_id:
            print("First Name: {}\tLast Name: {}".format(row[0].value, row[1].value))
            break
  else: # note the indentation
      print('Not found.')
```

**Please note**:
`row` is a `tuple` with three column in your case, I would better use some more generice way to access each part of the `tuple` :-)

Comment: This is the same as the existing code: openpyxl allows shortcuts for accessing rows or columns directly.

Comment: @DavidDr90 Thank you so much. It works! How can I use a flag?

Comment: @RobinSage just use `Python` `for-else` implementeation. I edit my answer and add code for it